# CSS: Which is more efficient, Inline styles or Css classes with !important to override styles

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, parceljs, inline-styles

I am building a widget on React with CRA and parcel to bundle, which can be added to other websites via a small JS script in index HTML. Used CSS modules for styling the components. I try adding this widget to a WordPress website, the CSS from WP pages override the CSS styles of the components.

I could think about two solutions to retain my styles:

1. Inline styles to all components
2. Adding !important to all CSS properties in CSS classes (recommended to be used sparingly)

Will there be a performance hit due to increase in page size due to inline styles
Also worried about not being able to use pseudo elements or media queries if I go with inline styles

I hope there some way to achieve this, some packages in react will helpful.

Comment: `!important` is a tool of last resort; it almost always means that your CSS "architecture" has a problem.

Comment: just create an override stylesheet that is more specific than the styles you want to override (eg put the component in a div with a class and then use that on top of the existing selector to override it)